# How to modify intent when "Don't keep activities" is enabled?

Tags: android

The app has `SplashActivity` which is launched both normally and via deep link. In later case the `SplashActivity` creates an `Intent`, sets the data from deeplink, and launches `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` checks the data and behaves differently for normal launches and deep link launches.

When I enable "Don't keep activities" and launch the app via deeplink then when I go to background and return to the `MainActivity` it is recreated with deeplink intent.

I tried to modify the `Intent` in `onDestroy` and `onSaveInstanceState` with `removeExtra` and `setIntent`, but when I go to background and back the intent is still the same from deeplink and the extra is still there. I also tried to check intent flags for `LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` but when I debugged the app flags were 0 every time.

I don't need the app to behave like it was launched with deeplink when it was launched from history. Is it possible to preserve intent modifications in that case?

Comment: start sharing code

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your intent in onPause, everything you do after onPause will not be saved, you may even consider modify your intent just after you consumed it to make your deeplink, i guess this will work as well

Comment: I just tried `onPause` and after consuming, I still get the extra in `onCreate`

Answer (score -1):

In `onCreate` block, Try removing the deep-linking keys in the `Intent` that you send to the activity

```
int flags = getIntent().getFlags();
if ((flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
   // The activity was launched from history
   // remove extras here to prevent the app from retaining the deep linking intent
   getIntent().removeExtra(key);
 } else {
    // get data from intent normally
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra(key)
 }
```

This should prevent the `Activity` from retaining the previous `Intent`.